# How can I execute AT command(gsm module) using java in Windows 10?

Tags: java, serial-port, gsm, at-command

I want to send and receive SMS from a java application using GSM module. I am working on windows 10. I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39444744/send-at-command-to-gsm-modem-with-java) answer. But that doesn't work for me.

Comment: This is a site about programming question. You have to include all the relevant code in the question. What have you tried? What are you expecting and what are you experiencing? IN FULL DETAILS.

Comment: I have tried and googled for a week. but unable to find any resource to learn. I hardly know about it. My goal is to send and receive SMS from JavaFX application on the Windows-10 platform.