# Send At Command to gsm modem with Java to read sms

Tags: java, at-command, gsmcomm

I have been searching about this problem; I read about rxtx, javacom, smslib etc. I have found several article but I can't really understand it because I'm a beginner.

Actually I found some good article that can send SMS here [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39444744/send-at-command-to-gsm-modem-with-java) but the problem is I want to read incoming sms then delete it after that.

I have found that I can do that by using AT+CMGR, AT+CMGL from [here](http://www.developershome.com/sms/readSmsByAtCommands.asp)

What syntax in Java do I need to try the AT+CMGR and AT+CMGL to read the sms and at least print it?

I already succeed to check which port is ready by using this code:

```
package anothersms;
import gnu.io.*;
import java.util.Enumeration;

public class CommPortTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Program Started!!!");

        CommPortIdentifier serialPortId;

        Enumeration enumComm;

        enumComm = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();

        while(enumComm.hasMoreElements())
        {
            serialPortId = (CommPortIdentifier)enumComm.nextElement();
            if(serialPortId.getPortType() == CommPortIdentifier.PORT_SERIAL)
            {
                System.out.println(serialPortId.getName());
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Program Finished Sucessfully");
    }

}
```

After long way to setting DLL etc I find that works, but still I barely understand it.

Answer (score 1):

I get it the code to read and delete the message. But it doesn't use at command, its using `smslib`, but still its simple enough so i don't really confused.

i get the code from [here](https://github.com/tdelenikas/smslib-v3/blob/master/src/java/examples/modem/ReadMessages.java), the code even giving us ability to listen if there is incoming message and notify us.

Furthermore i add some code to delete incoming message after read it. Here is the code

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import org.smslib.AGateway;
import org.smslib.AGateway.GatewayStatuses;
import org.smslib.AGateway.Protocols;
import org.smslib.GatewayException;
import org.smslib.ICallNotification;
import org.smslib.IGatewayStatusNotification;
import org.smslib.IInboundMessageNotification;
import org.smslib.IOrphanedMessageNotification;
import org.smslib.InboundMessage;
import org.smslib.InboundMessage.MessageClasses;
import org.smslib.Library;
import org.smslib.Message.MessageTypes;
import org.smslib.Service;
import org.smslib.TimeoutException;
import org.smslib.crypto.AESKey;
import org.smslib.modem.SerialModemGateway;

public class ReadMessages {

    public void doIt() throws Exception {
        // Define a list which will hold the read messages.
        List<InboundMessage> msgList;
        // Create the notification callback method for inbound & status report
        // messages.
        InboundNotification inboundNotification = new InboundNotification();
        // Create the notification callback method for inbound voice calls.
        CallNotification callNotification = new CallNotification();
        //Create the notification callback method for gateway statuses.
        GatewayStatusNotification statusNotification = new GatewayStatusNotification();
        OrphanedMessageNotification orphanedMessageNotification = new OrphanedMessageNotification();
        try {
            System.out.println("Example: Read messages from a serial gsm modem.");
            System.out.println(Library.getLibraryDescription());
            System.out.println("Version: " + Library.getLibraryVersion());
            // Create the Gateway representing the serial GSM modem.
            SerialModemGateway gateway = new SerialModemGateway("", "COM3", 115200, "", "");
            // Set the modem protocol to PDU (alternative is TEXT). PDU is the default, anyway...
            gateway.setProtocol(Protocols.PDU);
            // Do we want the Gateway to be used for Inbound messages?
            gateway.setInbound(true);
            // Do we want the Gateway to be used for Outbound messages?
            gateway.setOutbound(true);
            // Let SMSLib know which is the SIM PIN.
            gateway.setSimPin("0000");
            // Set up the notification methods.
            Service.getInstance().setInboundMessageNotification(inboundNotification);
            Service.getInstance().setCallNotification(callNotification);
            Service.getInstance().setGatewayStatusNotification(statusNotification);
            Service.getInstance().setOrphanedMessageNotification(orphanedMessageNotification);
            // Add the Gateway to the Service object.
            Service.getInstance().addGateway(gateway);
            // Similarly, you may define as many Gateway objects, representing
            // various GSM modems, add them in the Service object and control all of them.
            // Start! (i.e. connect to all defined Gateways)
            Service.getInstance().startService();
            // Printout some general information about the modem.
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Modem Information:");
            System.out.println("  Manufacturer: " + gateway.getManufacturer());
            System.out.println("  Model: " + gateway.getModel());
            System.out.println("  Serial No: " + gateway.getSerialNo());
            System.out.println("  SIM IMSI: " + gateway.getImsi());
            System.out.println("  Signal Level: " + gateway.getSignalLevel() + " dBm");
            System.out.println("  Battery Level: " + gateway.getBatteryLevel() + "%");
            System.out.println();
            // In case you work with encrypted messages, its a good time to declare your keys.
            // Create a new AES Key with a known key value. 
            // Register it in KeyManager in order to keep it active. SMSLib will then automatically
            // encrypt / decrypt all messages send to / received from this number.
            Service.getInstance().getKeyManager().registerKey("+306948494037", new AESKey(new SecretKeySpec("0011223344556677".getBytes(), "AES")));
            // Read Messages. The reading is done via the Service object and
            // affects all Gateway objects defined. This can also be more directed to a specific
            // Gateway - look the JavaDocs for information on the Service method calls.
            msgList = new ArrayList<InboundMessage>();
            Service.getInstance().readMessages(msgList, MessageClasses.ALL);
//                                              
            for (InboundMessage msg : msgList) {
                System.out.println(msg);
                String idx = msg.getMpMemIndex();
                Service.getInstance().deleteMessage(msg);
                System.out.println(">>> Message with index " + idx + " has been deleted");
            }

            // Sleep now. Emulate real world situation and give a chance to the notifications
            // methods to be called in the event of message or voice call reception.
            System.out.println("Now Sleeping - Hit <enter> to stop service.");
            System.in.read();
            System.in.read();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            Service.getInstance().stopService();
        }
    }

    public class InboundNotification implements IInboundMessageNotification {

        public void process(AGateway gateway, MessageTypes msgType, InboundMessage msg) {
            if (msgType == MessageTypes.INBOUND) {
                System.out.println(">>> New Inbound message detected from Gateway: " + gateway.getGatewayId());
                System.out.println(msg);
                String idx = msg.getMpMemIndex();
                try {
//                    Service.getInstance().wait(2);
                    Service.getInstance().deleteMessage(msg);
                    System.out.println(">>> Message with index " + idx + " has been deleted");
                } catch (TimeoutException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(ReadMessages.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    System.out.println(ex);
                } catch (GatewayException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(ReadMessages.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    System.out.println(ex);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(ReadMessages.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    System.out.println(ex);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(ReadMessages.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    System.out.println(ex);
                }
            } else if (msgType == MessageTypes.STATUSREPORT) {
                System.out.println(">>> New Inbound Status Report message detected from Gateway: " + gateway.getGatewayId());
            }

        }
    }

    public class CallNotification implements ICallNotification {

        public void process(AGateway gateway, String callerId) {
            System.out.println(">>> New call detected from Gateway: " + gateway.getGatewayId() + " : " + callerId);
        }
    }

    public class GatewayStatusNotification implements IGatewayStatusNotification {

        public void process(AGateway gateway, GatewayStatuses oldStatus, GatewayStatuses newStatus) {
            System.out.println(">>> Gateway Status change for " + gateway.getGatewayId() + ", OLD: " + oldStatus + " -> NEW: " + newStatus);
        }
    }

    public class OrphanedMessageNotification implements IOrphanedMessageNotification {

        public boolean process(AGateway gateway, InboundMessage msg) {
            System.out.println(">>> Orphaned message part detected from " + gateway.getGatewayId());
            System.out.println(msg);
            // Since we are just testing, return FALSE and keep the orphaned message part.
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        ReadMessages app = new ReadMessages();
        try {
            app.doIt();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Peter Hadded   can you tell me how to make smslib look like that? that's cool

Comment: Example: Read messages from a serial gsm modem.
SMSLib: A Java API library for sending and receiving SMS via a GSM modem or other supported gateways.
This software is distributed under the terms of the Apache v2.0 License.
Web Site: http://smslib.org
Version: 3.5.0
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.smslib.Service
 at webelement.ReadMessages.doIt(ReadMessages.java:94)
 at webelement.ReadMessages.main(ReadMessages.java:140)